Querying and ordering multiple entry and exit dates
For my data in question, I'm tracking student long-term absences from a PHD program. This could be due to an internship, medical issue, or personal reasons. The data looks like this:



Student ID
Action
Effective Date




A1
Leave
2024-01-01


A1
Return
2024-03-01


A1
Leave
2024-06-01


A1
Return
2024-08-01


A1
Leave
2025-01-01


A1
Return
2025-06-01


A2
Leave
2024-01-01


A2
Return
2024-05-01



Assume students can leave and return 3 separate times maximum
The end result of what I want is:



Student ID
Absence Number
Leave Date
Return Date




A1
1
2024-01-01
2024-03-01


A1
2
2024-06-01
2024-08-01


A1
3
2025-01-01
2025-06-01


A2
1
2024-01-01
2024-05-01



Wondering how to best achieve this.. I know CTEs are an option.. but the confusing part is how to get the first leave date vs the second leave date etc. Would I use RANK or ROW_NUMBER here, or something else?

here is one way including the absence_count :
with cte as (
  select *
  , row_number() over (partition by student_id,action order by effective_date) as rn
  from temp_student_actions
  ) 

select student_id 
  , row_number() over (partition by student_id order by student_id) no_of_absence
  , max(case when action='Leave' then effective_date end) leave_date
  , max(case when action='Return' then effective_date end) return_date 
from cte 
group by student_id, rn 
order by student_id, leave_date

output:



student_id
no_of_absence
leave_date
return_date




A1
1
2024-01-01
2024-03-01


A1
2
2024-06-01
2024-08-01


A1
3
2025-01-01
2025-06-01


A2
1
2024-01-01
2024-05-01



fiddle

this works perfect but can you explain why the main query is using so many aggregates?

@Yoav24 to get the result you want! , that's where the aggregation is used for

lmao killing me but ok

Yes, there is always a way to achieve this. Here is how it can be done by using the combination of ROW_NUMBER() and LAG() functions in the SQL server.
Here is the query
WITH Absences AS (
  SELECT StudentID, Action, EffectiveDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID, Action ORDER BY EffectiveDate) AS RowNum,
         CASE Action WHEN 'Leave' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END AS ActionSign
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT StudentID,
       SUM(ActionSign) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY EffectiveDate) AS AbsenceNumber,
       CASE Action WHEN 'Leave' THEN EffectiveDate END AS LeaveDate,
       LAG(CASE Action WHEN 'Return' THEN EffectiveDate END, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY EffectiveDate) AS ReturnDate
FROM Absences
WHERE Action IN ('Leave', 'Return')
ORDER BY StudentID, EffectiveDate;

The first part is CTE I called it Absences assigns a row to each row within each student's leave/return sequence using ROW_NUMBER()
The main query uses a window function (SUM and OVER) to calculate the absence number for each student.
The CASE statement filters and LAG function is use to get the previous data.
Here is the output.
StudentID  AbsenceNumber  LeaveDate    ReturnDate
A1        1             2024-01-01   2024-03-01
A1        2             2024-06-01   2024-08-01
A1        3             2025-01-01   2025-06-01
A2        1             2024-01-01   2024-05-01


unfortunately this code does not work.. also the SUM would return a 0 every time, no?

Here's an option using the window function row_number() and a conditional aggregation
Example
with cte as ( 
Select *
      ,Grp = row_number() over (partition by [Student ID],Action order by [Effective Date])
 From  @YourTable 
)
Select [Student ID]
      ,[Leave Date]  = max(case when Action='Leave'  then [Effective Date] end)
      ,[Return Date] = max(case when Action='Return' then [Effective Date] end)
 From cte 
 Group By [Student ID]
         ,Grp
 Order By [Student ID],[Leave Date]

Results
Student ID  Leave Date  Return Date
A1          2024-01-01  2024-03-01
A1          2024-06-01  2024-08-01
A2          2024-01-01  2024-05-01
A3          2025-01-01  NULL


very cool, i will try this! note I changed the original data table a bit
